# Row selection is not working in a JTable

Tags: java, netbeans, jtable

I have created a JTable but for some reason row selection is not working (I am using mac and Nimbus L&F).

Here is the code :

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package nysemarketpick;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Vector;
import javax.swing.event.TableModelEvent;
import javax.swing.event.TableModelListener;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableRowSorter;

/**
 *
 * @author Administrator
 */
public class PortfolioForm extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form PortfolioForm
     */
    public PortfolioForm() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jbtAddRow = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jbtDeleteRow = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTable1 = new javax.swing.JTable();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jPanel1.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Row functions"));

        jbtAddRow.setText("Add New Row");

        jbtDeleteRow.setText("Delete Selected Row");

        org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
            .add(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .add(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
                    .add(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .add(34, 34, 34)
                        .add(jbtAddRow))
                    .add(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .add(16, 16, 16)
                        .add(jbtDeleteRow)))
                .addContainerGap(40, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
            .add(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .add(jbtAddRow)
                .add(18, 18, 18)
                .add(jbtDeleteRow)
                .addContainerGap(26, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        jTable1.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
        jTable1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {
                {null, null, null, null, null}
            },
            new String [] {
                "Stock Symbol", "Stock Name", "Shares", "Value (in Dollars)", "Total Value"
            }
        ) {
            Class[] types = new Class [] {
                java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.Integer.class, java.lang.Double.class, java.lang.Double.class
            };
            boolean[] canEdit = new boolean [] {
                true, false, true, true, false
            };

            public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
                return types [columnIndex];
            }

            public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
                return canEdit [columnIndex];
            }
        });
        tableModel = (DefaultTableModel)jTable1.getModel();
        jTable1.setColumnSelectionAllowed(true);
        jTable1.setRowSelectionAllowed(true);
        jTable1.setSelectionMode(javax.swing.ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTable1);
        jTable1.getColumnModel().getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(javax.swing.ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        //add action listeners
        jbtAddRow.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                if (jTable1.getSelectedRow() >= 0)
                tableModel.insertRow(jTable1.getSelectedRow(), new Vector());
                else
                tableModel.addRow(new Vector());
            }
        });
        jbtDeleteRow.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                if (jTable1.getSelectedRow() >= 0)
                tableModel.removeRow(jTable1.getSelectedRow());
            }
        });
        //add other listeners
        tableModel.addTableModelListener(new TableModelListener(){
            public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e)
            {
                DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)e.getSource();
                //Object data = model.getValueAt(e.getFirstRow(), e.getColumn());
                if (e.getColumn() == 0)
                {
                    Object data = model.getValueAt(e.getFirstRow(), e.getColumn());
                    String stockSymbol = (String)data;
                    XMLService2 myService = new XMLService2(stockSymbol);
                    String stockName = XMLService2.getStockName();
                    model.setValueAt(stockName, e.getFirstRow(), e.getColumn() + 1);
                }
                if (e.getColumn() != 4 && model.getValueAt(e.getFirstRow(), 2) != null && model.getValueAt(e.getFirstRow(), 3) != null)
                {
                    Double myDouble =(Integer)model.getValueAt(e.getFirstRow(), 2)*(Double)model.getValueAt(e.getFirstRow(), 3);
                    model.setValueAt(myDouble, e.getFirstRow(), 4);
                }
            }
        });

        org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout layout = new org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
            .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
                    .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .add(21, 21, 21)
                        .add(jScrollPane1, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 645, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .add(31, 31, 31)
                        .add(jPanel1, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addContainerGap(50, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
            .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .add(jScrollPane1, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 399, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .add(27, 27, 27)
                .add(jPanel1, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(PortfolioForm.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(PortfolioForm.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(PortfolioForm.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(PortfolioForm.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new PortfolioForm().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTable jTable1;
    private DefaultTableModel tableModel;
    private javax.swing.JButton jbtAddRow;
    private javax.swing.JButton jbtDeleteRow;
    // End of variables declaration
}
```

Any ideas on this one are more than welcome.
Thank you.

Comment: Please spare us NetBeans auto generated code and someone could even answer your question. Thank you!

Comment: Agree, that code is completely unnecessary and unrelated to your problem. Consider creating and posting an [sscce](http://sscce.org) with only code needed to run the program and display the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that you have set

```
jTable1.setColumnSelectionAllowed(true);
```

which effectively limits the selection range to one cell. Setting to the default false will allow you to select a whole row.